# Unused baked potatoes

Tags: baking, potatoes

I work in a cafe but I am still a little new to some things so my question is: If I turn yesterday's bakers into today's mashed potatoes will they taste any different? I am concerned that they may look different  or taste less fresh.

Comment: Do you normally use the same type of potato for both? I generally don't use bakers for mashed potatoes... and I don't generally bake them because they dry out. How do you usually prepare each type of potato/dish and what do you usually use for them?

Comment: @Catija I always learned red or boiling potatoes for mash, russets for baking.  But I am learning more and more that many good cooks, talking the Gordon Ramsey types, not only use russets, they bake them first, then put them through a ricer for fluffier mashes, while sticking with boilers for chunkier and skin on mashes.  I am not sure how well using a ricer would go with cold though, I have only done it and had good results while the bakers are still hot.

Comment: If you don't use them for mashed potatoes, they work rather well for hash or home fries.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this in the past and it does work well (think about twice baked potatoes...) but there are few considerations. You will need to add more butter or cream to the baked potatoes and it does work better if you are mixing it with boiled potatoes. I don't recall there ever being enough left over bakers that we didn't need to add at least some fresh potatoes.

---

bonus: then you can use the left over mash potatoes to make potato rolls for the next night :)